# h:commandLink with Java bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jstl, commandlink

I have a datalist"gouvernorats" extracted from a data table and each item of the list is a command link that outcome an other page which contains a list "villes" referenced to the item. My code doesn't work.I ask someone to help me running it.

gouvernorat.xhtml
`<c:forEach varStatus="#{stat}" items="gouvernoratbean.gouvernorats" var="gouv"><c:set var="villes" scope="request" value="${gouv.getvilles}"/>
 <h:commandLink  action="ville" actionListener="#{gouvernoratbean.showville}" value="#{gouv.nomGouv}"><f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{requestscope.gouv}" value="#{gouv}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
 </h:commandLink></c:forEach>`

ville.xhtml

`<p:dataList value="#{requestScope.gouvernoratbean.showville}" var="ville"  >
  <h:outputText><h2>#{ville.nomVille}</h2> </h:outputText> </p:dataList>`

gouvernoratbean.java

`public void showville(ActionEvent event){Villes=gouv.getVilles();}`

Comment: I have a datalist"gouvernorats" extracted from a data table and each item of the list is a command link that outcome an other page which contains a list "villes" referenced to the item.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question, you just posted some code. What are you looking for?

Comment: My code doesn't work.So I need your help to run it.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what your actual question is..

But it may not working as you have not referenced your bean properly in this part of the xhtml:

```
items="gouvernoratbean.gouvernorats"
```

Should be:

`items="#{gouvernoratbean.gouvernorats}"`.

Comment: I have a datalist which contains the governorates and each item is a commandlink that shows the different cities of the concerned governate.

Comment: Right... this is still not a question which I can try to answer? What are you trying to achieve and what errors are you facing?